# Difference between "at the drop of a hat" and "in no time"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms '**at the drop of a hat**' and '**in no time**'? The definitions in the Collins Dictionary are:

- **at the drop of a hat:** If you say that you are ready to do something at the drop of a hat, you mean that you are willing to do it immediately, without hesitating.
- **in no time:** very quickly; almost instantaneously

Comment: I could drive to London at the drop of a hat (just grabbing my car keys and putting my shoes on), but it would still take me four hours.

Comment: _At the drop of a hat_ implies spontaneity, not speed.

Answer (score 1):

Some difference. Both are exaggerations.

**In no time** means the action takes a very short time to perform. Even weeding for 2 hours could be "I'll have it done in no time."

**At the drop of a hat** means starting the action anytime, with even the smallest drop of reason or warning, like when the wind blows or a man tips his. Or drops it.

"So let me get right to the point, I don't pop my cork for every man I see." Sure she does - a dancehall girl is paid to "pop her cork" at the drop of a hat (mixed metaphor there).

Comment: When the wind blows? At the tip of his hat?